# How to initialize class in VB the right way?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Question for the VB experts here!

I have the following code in C#:

```cs
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty()
    {
        Headers =
        {
            "test", "test"
        }
    };
    request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestProperty);
    return null;
}
```

I have tried to turn this into VB code like this:

```vb
Public Function BeforeSendRequest(ByRef request As Message, ByVal channel As IClientChannel) As Object
    Dim httpRequestProperty As HttpRequestMessageProperty = New HttpRequestMessageProperty() With {
        .Headers = {
            {"test", "test"}
        }
    }
    request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestProperty)
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

To my understanding this should be correct, but Visual Studio is complaining that Headers is a readonly property. This though should not be a problem when I am initializing a class. Any idea why this is the case? To my understanding C# and VB should be similar that I should be able to do this. If for some reason this isn't possible in VB, how can I achieve the same as in my C# code?

Comment: Better question is why are you using `Properties` when it's been marked as deprecated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collection initializers for read-only collection properties in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817741/collection-initializers-for-read-only-collection-properties-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the C# syntax is not actually assigning `Headers` to a new value (it is indeed `readonly` and cannot be assigned, even in an initializer), but rather calling `Headers.Add` on each of the items in the collection.

The equivalent C# code for the inlined initializer with a collection property would be:

```
HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty()
httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("test", "test")
```

note that `Headers` is not being *set*, but is set internally, and an `Add` call is created.

The canonical way to do that in VB would be:

```
Dim httpRequestProperty As HttpRequestMessageProperty = New HttpRequestMessageProperty()
httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("test", "test")
```

There may be a slicker VB syntax to inline the adds, but I would start with something that works and then decide if it's worth the time and effort to find a way to inline it.

Comment: From this, I think using `New HttpRequestMessageProperty From {{"test", "test"}}` ought to work.  I'm not sure if you could inline it into the initialization of the request property, though.

Comment: I don't think so, because it would be equivalent to calling `Add` on the `HttpRequestMessageProperty` (which doesn't exist), not the `.Headers` property.

Comment: I usually have used object initialization in C# like I created an object with a constructor, so I may have totally misunderstood what actually happens under the hood. However this solution worked. Thanks a lot! My first project where I have had to write some VB, so I am a bit confused still.

Comment: Unfortunately VB does not get all of the syntactic sugars that C# does, so it's helpful to know what they actually do. In this case, it does not use a constructor parameter but uses the default constructor followed by property setters (which are not allowed for `readonly` properties. You can, however, use [`init` accessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init) which are settable only during initialization.

Comment: Oops, I actually meant `New WebHeaderCollection From {{"test", "test"}}` since that's the collection-like object that has an `Add` (which is what `From` converts to).

Comment: @Craig the problem is that you cannot set the `Headers` property to the new object because it's read-only. It's designed to encapsulate the headers into a read-only class that you can only add/remove values to/from.

Comment: Sure, which means that there is only limited opportunity to inline declarations.  I suspected that it might be something like this going on.  I'd suggest adding the info you've included in the comments into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Public Function BeforeSendRequest(ByRef request As Message, ByVal channel As IClientChannel) As Object
    Dim headers As New WebHeaderCollection()
    headers.Add("test", "test")
    
    Dim httpRequestProperty As New HttpRequestMessageProperty() With {
        .Headers = headers
    }

    request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestProperty)
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: This unfortunately still complains about Headers being read only.